# Python RegEx matching only the inside regex

Tags: python, regex

I have found the solution to this problem on StackOverflow sometime ago but couldn't find the solution again.
I want to extract a pattern from a string.

```
my_string ='hello ,mister synonyms: fine, of high quality, of a high standard, quality, superior; More'
```

I want to extract `'fine, of high quality, of a high standard, quality, superior'`

I used

```
match_obj = re.search(r'(synonyms: )((\w+,|; )+)', my_string)
print(match_obj.group(2))
```

It gives only `'fine,'`
I know there is something wrong in the way I am writing regex for the nested brackets in this case but I am unable to find the right way to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the substring with comma-separated values first (you can do it with `(?<=synonyms: )[^;]+` regex that only matches 1 or more characters other than `;` after `synonyms:`  substring), and then split with `\s*,\s*` regex (it will trim the values, too, thanks to the whitespace matched with `\s*`) to get the necessary values:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?<=synonyms: )[^;]+')
test_str = "hello ,mister synonyms: fine, of high quality, of a high standard, quality, superior; More"
o = re.search(p, test_str)
if o:
    s = o.group()
    print re.split(r"\s*,\s*", s)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/4Nvpxd)

## UPDATE

Since your intention is to learn capturing and non-capturing groups, here is your fixed regex:

```
(synonyms: )((?:\s*\w+,?)+)
```

And the explanation:

- `(synonyms: )` - The first capturing group matching literally `synonyms:`
- `((?:\s*\w+,?)+)` - The second capturing group that matches

  - `(?:\s*\w+,?)+` - 1 or more non-capturing sequence (i.e. it will not be stored in the stack) of

    - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters
    - `\w+` - 1 or more word characters (`[A-Za-z0-9_]`)
    - `,?` - 0 or 1 comma

[Demo is available here](https://regex101.com/r/vI5cP4/1).

Note 4 things:

1. You do not have to capture literal texts. You know them already, there is just no point in that.
2. Python `re` engine does not remember multiple captured groups as in .NET (where we have `.Captures` property), thus, we cannot use a capturing group to get all individual comma-separated values that easily. Nor does Python support `\G` in regex to get consecutive matches.
3. To obtain the individual entries, in Python, we'll have to split the obtain string as a second step (of course, if you need to).
4. Thinking about optimization, you can see that in the regex, the `(?:\s*\w+,?)+` part looks tricky, but the point is that all 3 components - `\s`, `\w` and `,` **cannot match the same text**. It is important to follow the same tactics when you write really complex regexps with `+` quantifier set to the whole group.

Comment: I don't think you need the split if you do `p = re.compile(r'(?<=synonyms: )(.*?)[^;]+')` and `str = re.search(p, test_str).group(0)`

Comment: I understood that OP needs the comma-separated values. The result of my code is `['fine', 'of high quality', 'of a high standard', 'quality', 'superior']`. Well, if only a part of it is sufficient, I am happy with that.

Comment: This solution works great but the thing is, I wanted to know how to do the same with my approach.

Comment: Special thanks for the 4 points. If I may ask, why have you used `?:` in the regex? I tried it without that and it worked.

Comment: People say non-capturing groups create less overhead, and they produce a cleaner match, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to match whatever is between `"synonyms: "` and `";"`, then you could use one of the following:

```
(synonyms: )([\w, ]+|[^;])+
(synonyms: )(\w+, [^;]+)+
(synonyms: )(.+)(?=;)
(synonyms: )([^;]+)
```

Comment: Well, technically yes. You are correct. But somehow I thought of that way and I am pissed off because I am not able to make it work.

Comment: @Shivendra I guess if I were going to modify what you have there, I might try:  `(synonyms: )([^;]+)` or `(synonyms: )([\w, ]+|[^;])+`.  Is that the sort of answer you're looking for?

Comment: Ummm, I think I am a terrible OP. Your answer works fine. What I wanted to know was why my double bracketed approach `((something)+)` was not working. And seeing @stribizhev's answer I realised my `something` was wrong. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want to match everything after `synonyms:` up to the semicolon?

```
r'(synonyms: )([\w, ]+)'
```

See it in action: https://regex101.com/r/jI0dV4/1

I think the flaw in your regex was essentially the placement of the `|`.
This makes the regex match **either** `\w,` **or** `;_`   (`_` denotes space)

Note that the grouping with the round brackets always introduces new capturing groups.
I used square brackets to list the allowed characters.

If you follow the [link](https://regex101.com/r/jI0dV4/1) you can try out different things and get instant results and explanations.

Comment: Your solution works great but sir, I wanted to correct my solution, i.e. I want to learn to use complex regex (with regex brackets) inside a group.

Comment: @Shivendra tried to give an explanation to your problem as well.

Comment: I am aware that round brackets introduce new capturing groups but I wanted a workaround which still uses them and not any other alternative way. Thank you sir for helping.

Answer (score 1):

This will capture everything between "synonyms:" and ";" into a single string. Because the positive lookbehind `(?<=synonyms: )` is a zero-width, non-capturing assertion, the only capture group will be zero `([^;]+)`.

```
test_str = "hello ,mister synonyms: fine, of high quality, of a high standard, quality, superior; More"
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=synonyms: )([^;]+)')
string = regex.search(test_str).group(0)

print(string)
```